# check header type content-url

Tags: image, http, url, content-type

What is the easiest way to check the content type of a URL? I have an image url and I needed to figure out what the content-type is, can I do this easily using chrome/firefox web tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. In Chrome, press ctrl+shift+J, switch to the "Network" tab of the development console, and refresh the page. Click on the image in question (you may have to wait for it to load) and then select the "headers" tab. It will show you all headers (including `content-type`) that were sent in response to your image request.

I know FF has similar tools, but Chrome is open right now...so that's what you get! :^)

Answer (score 0):

curl would work; all you need is a HEAD request, e.g.:

```
curl -vvv -X HEAD 'http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d31c8d7d3cf640a6b29d9ad71788dd4a.png'
```

Alternately, any http library that supports the HEAD method would work too. That would be helpful if you need to do it inside a program.